# Angular Component to make not inherit default css style

Tags: css, angular, web, single-page-application

I am newbie in Angular, do not blame me if something I explained wrong ...

I have started learning of Angular and faced with the problem:
How to separate style of my component from default style in Web App ?

It is useful when you find a nice Angular Component on the Web, copy it in your application and it looks like as was intended.

I have found on the Web that something like this possible with:

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
```

But seems it doesn't work ...
Is there any solution for such case ?

Comment: If you not use ViewEncapsulation.None, all the styles defined in your component in styles or urlstyles apply only to the component. If you want override some style, you can do it in these properties, see documentation https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: @Eliseo Okay, it is understandable, but I have used http://materializecss.com in the head of html document and it broke me my component style. Is there any solution to protect from global styles in my component ? And if no how to use such css frameworks within Angular without breaking styles on components that I copied from the Web ?